# How to add a button link in header of home page but different in others?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, header

I need to add a button of login and sign up in the header of first page, but it different from others page. I am just a new to react.js, just have some of the knowledge of this hope anyone of you will help me. If you need more detail, please comments at below.

Here is my home page:

```
class Welcome extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super();
      this.state ={
        appName: 'Event Management System'

      }
  }

  render(){
    return (
        <div className="row small-up-2 medium-up-3 large-up-4">
          <div className="column">
          <h2> Project Description </h2>
            <a href="/login" className="button">Login</a>
            <a href="/SignUp" className="button primary">SignUp</a>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is App.js:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super();
      this.state ={
        appName: 'Event Management System'
      }
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="off-canvas-wrapper">
        <div className="off-canvas-wrapper-inner" data-off-canvas-wrapper>
          <div className="off-canvas-content" data-off-canvas-content>
            <MobileHeader  name={this.state.appName}/>
            <Header name={this.state.appName}/>
            <Routes />
            <hr/>
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and here is header.js

```
class Header extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="callout primary" id="Header">
        <div className="row column">
          <h1> {this.props.name} </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What i need is like this in first page:
[image]

Comment: upload u r code here (https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-kowalevski-wcr45) and share the link

Answer (score 1):

In your header component you can put this in your return:

```
{document.pathname === '/home' ? <button></button> : ""}
```

(Edit: remember that a jsx requires everything to be wrapped in one element, so if you're showing 2 buttons you'll have to do this twice or wrap the two button elements in another element like a div)

Essentially render the button IF document.pathname EQUALS the path of the page you want it to show on. If you're using state to manage the page rather than a router, use the state for your condition instead.